# how to prevent greasemonkey script running on 2 pages together

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a greasemonkey script which loads on every page of a website.
The script posts a particular data at regular interval using jquery.

The problem is when the user opens a new tab the the data gets posted twice at the same time.
How can i prevent this ?

is there a function which will prevent one of the script to prevent posting while the other script is already running on the other page. Or some other workaround ?

**Update:**

The script is a auto auction bidder.
So when the deadline arrives all the open tab will try to post the bid together that would post multiple bids at the same time which i don't want.

Comment: You could store in localStorage the time of last post.

Comment: but that would not be a full-proof method the prevent the situation

Comment: the only full-proof methods are server side of course. Do you want to protect the user or the server ?

Comment: Define "same page". Are the URLs **exactly** the same?  If so, why do you have more than one tab open?  And more than one tab for the same auction?

Comment: The urls can be any thing but the domain is same. (eg http://domain.com/*) and yes the greasemonkey script will try to submit the bid even if the user is on the homepage of website.